# How to Check if PostgreSQL Array Contains Value greater than a Value

Tags: postgresql

Let's say I have several records with a column in type `int[]`, and I want to find all the records containing at least one value greater than 200 in the array. How should I achieve that?

Sample data:

```
array
-------------
{18}
{489}
{218, 333, 100}
{23, 44, 102}
```

I would need to locate the second and third rows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE 200 < ANY(arr);
```